# how do I check the value of two pickers jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, picker

There is a popup picker where two users enter their weight. The first picker is for the current weight of the user and the second is for the target weight. In these pickers, the user chooses kilos and grams.
My codes are like this

**UI**

```
when (state.pickerState) {

        PickerState.CURRENT_WEIGHT -> {
            DailyCalorieWeightPickerComponent(
                onConfirmClick = { kg, gr ->
                    onChangeCurrentWeight(kg, gr)
                    onChangePickerStatus(PickerState.NONE)
                },
                onCancelClick = {
                    onChangePickerStatus(PickerState.NONE)
                },
                currentGr = state.currentGr,
                currentKg = state.currentKg,
                goalKg = state.goalKg,
                goalGr = state.goalGr,
                isClickGoalWeight = false
            )
        }
        PickerState.GOAL_WEIGHT -> {
            DailyCalorieWeightPickerComponent(
                onConfirmClick = { kg, gr ->
                    onChangeGoalWeight(kg, gr)
                    onChangePickerStatus(PickerState.NONE)
                },
                onCancelClick = {
                    onChangePickerStatus(PickerState.NONE)
                },
                currentGr = state.currentGr,
                currentKg = state.currentKg,
                goalKg = state.goalKg,
                goalGr = state.goalGr,
                isClickGoalWeight = true
            )
        }

        PickerState.NONE -> {
            // silence is golden
        }
    }
```

**DailyCalorieWeightPickerComponent component**

```
@Composable
fun DailyCalorieWeightPickerComponent(
    onConfirmClick: (Int, Int) -> Unit,
    onCancelClick: () -> Unit,
    currentKg: Int?,
    currentGr: Int?,
    goalKg: Int?,
    goalGr: Int?,
    isClickGoalWeight: Boolean
) {


    var kg by remember { mutableStateOf(value = 35) }
    var gr by remember { mutableStateOf(value = 0) }

    val kgRange = 35..200
    val grRange = 0..1000

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Gray)
                .padding(start = 0.dp, top = 30.dp, end = 0.dp, bottom = 0.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            NumberPicker(
                value = kg,
                onValueChange = { newKg ->
                    kg = newKg
                },
                range = kgRange
            )
            Text(text = "kg")
            NumberPicker(
                value = gr,
                onValueChange = { newGr ->
                    gr = newGr

                },
                range = grRange
            )
            Text(text = "gr")

        }
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                .background(Color.Gray)
                .padding(start = 0.dp, top = 15.dp, end = 0.dp, bottom = 15.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            TextButton(onClick = {
                onCancelClick()
            }) {
                Text(
                    text = "cancel",
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    color = DefaultDYTColor,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                )
            }
            Divider(
                color = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .fillMaxHeight()  //fill the max height
                    .width(1.dp)
            )

            TextButton(onClick = {
                onConfirmClick(kg, gr)
            }) {
                Text(
                    text = "okey",
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    color = DefaultDYTColor,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do something here, so I already get the currentKg currentGr goalKg and goalGr values ​​in this component, but I don't use them in this code for now. In this way, the user can choose his target weight and target gram, and also his current weight and current gram. As you can see in the code, the values ​​are between 35 and 200, and grams are between 0 and 1000. What I want to do is that the user's target weight will never be greater than his current weight, that is, I want to adjust his current weight to be greater than the target weight. for example the user has selected his target weight of 40 kg and 20 g. While choosing the current weight, I want to start from 41 kg and 21 g from the picker. In the same way, if the user has selected his first current weight, let's say 40 kg and 20 gr, when he clicks to select his target weight again, the picker will open and the picker will have the maximum value of 39 kg and can select 19 gr per gram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the range customisable in the `DailyCalorieWeightPickerComponent` component

```
@Composable
fun DailyCalorieWeightPickerComponent(
    onConfirmClick: (Int, Int) -> Unit,
    onCancelClick: () -> Unit,
    kgRange: IntRange, // pass range here
    grRange: IntRange,
    isClickGoalWeight: Boolean
) {
    var kg by remember { mutableStateOf(value = 35) }
    var gr by remember { mutableStateOf(value = 0) }
    //remove range here
```

Now you have set the ranges while rendering the component using current and target as

```
when (state.pickerState) {
    PickerState.CURRENT_WEIGHT -> {
        DailyCalorieWeightPickerComponent(
            onConfirmClick = { kg, gr ->
                onChangeCurrentWeight(kg, gr)
                onChangePickerStatus(PickerState.NONE)
            },
            onCancelClick = {
                onChangePickerStatus(PickerState.NONE)
            },
            kgRange = (state.goalKg + 1)..200, //start from 41
            grRange = (state.goalGram + 1)..1000,
            isClickGoalWeight = false
        )
    }
    PickerState.GOAL_WEIGHT -> {
        DailyCalorieWeightPickerComponent(
            onConfirmClick = { kg, gr ->
                onChangeGoalWeight(kg, gr)
                onChangePickerStatus(PickerState.NONE)
            },
            onCancelClick = {
                onChangePickerStatus(PickerState.NONE)
            },
            kgRange = 35 until state.currentKg, // maximum weight 39kg
            grRange = 0 until state.currentGr,
            isClickGoalWeight = false
        )
    }
    PickerState.NONE -> {
        // silence is golden
    }
}
```